# random output from random variable discord.py

Tags: python, random, printing, discord

here's the current code:

```
@client.command()
async def randousername(ctx):
    Letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    Numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

    randomLetter = random.choice(Letters)
    randomNumber = random.choice(Numbers)
    RandomRandom = random.choice('RandomLetter', 'RandomNumber')
    print(RandomRandom, RandomRandom)
```

now im gonna explain what I'm trying to do with it:

I'm trying to give a random output of numbers and letters. To make it fully random, I wanna make the `randomNumber` and `randomLetter`'s positions in the output also be random.

another explanation:
Let's say that I `print(randomNumber,randomLetter)`, and this printed "`2o`". the code will never be able to print "`o2`", since the `random number` is placed before the `random letter`.

⠀

***how would I be able to make that happen?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest will be to store [*randomly selected*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) chars in a list, [*shuffle*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) it and [*join*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) it into a string.

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
from random import choice, shuffle

tmp = [choice(ascii_lowercase), choice(digits)]
shuffle(tmp)
result = "".join(tmp)
```

If you prefer more compact solutions, here is one-liner:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
from random import choice, sample

result = "".join(sample(choice(ascii_lowercase) + choice(digits), k=2))
```

Comment: nice! now, what if I were to do more than one lowercased letter and digits? like "o2k52". Since 'choice' only takes 2 positional arguments..

Comment: @Mathe, you can use either [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) or [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) with `k` argument where you should pass count of chars selected. Difference between those functions is that `choices()` could return duplicates while `sample()` returns list of unique values. Notice, that to get string result, you should pass return of this function *(which is `list`)* into [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).